# Lua, table containing a function

Tags: function, types, lua, lua-table

I'm using the World of warcraft API. And I want to find an `EventMessageFilter`. I can do so by calling

```
ChatFrame_GetMessageEventFilters("event")
```

And to do this I have to pass a chat event, in my case `CHAT_MSG_WHISPER_INFORM`.

So according to the API located over at

http://wowprogramming.com/docs/api/ChatFrame_GetMessageEventFilters

This function will return a table. So I named the table and tried to print its content with this code

```
local myNewTable = filterTable = ChatFrame_GetMessageEventFilters("CHAT_MSG_WHISPER_INFORM")
for i in pairs(myNewTable) do
    print(asd[i])
end
```

And this then prints out something like

```
function: 00000312498vn27842934c4
```

I have checked with

```
type(asd[i])
```

and it really is a function. But how can I get the content of it? How do I handle it?

Answer (score 1):

> I want to find an EventMessageFilter

Can you elaborate? Whose filter are you looking for and what do you intend to do with it?

> it really is a function.

That's what this API does: returns a list of functions that are registered as filters for a particular message type (via `ChatFrame_AddMessageEventFilter`).

> But how can I get the content of it?

You can't. The WoW API doesn't offer you any facilities for decompiling functions.

If your intention is to filter chat messages yourself, you don't need to call this function at all. Just call [`ChatFrame_AddMessageEventFilter`](http://wowprogramming.com/docs/api/ChatFrame_AddMessageEventFilter) to add your filter.

Comment: I want to create an addon that will whisper my guild mates and tell them what target to call. But I want to hide these whispers from me so that I don't get a bunch of spam in my chat output.

Currently a popular RP addon called TRP3 disables my ability to add a message event filter to filter away my outgoing whispers. What I want to do is to look up the TRP3 chat filter event that is blocking my event to temporarily disable it.

I just read that the API returned a table of filters, but the type of them.

Comment: So this is a classic [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Your real problem is "TRP3 disables my ability to add a message event filter". How is that? What's preventing you from calling ChatFrame_AddMessageEventFilter?

Comment: It just doesn't work. Only if the addon is disabled. No lua errors or nothing. It's as if the event filter is not there.

Comment: Are you calling `ChatFrame_AddMessageEventFilter` correctly (event name, function)? Did you call `ChatFrame_GetMessageEventFilters` before and after adding your filter to see that the list of filters has grown by one? Can you find your filter in the list of filters? If it's there, have you verified that it's being called (e.g. print('xxx'))? Have you tried always returning true to ensure you can filter messages at all? Did you register to receive this event in the first place (via `RegisterEvent`)? So on and so forth. This is the problem you need to solve.

Comment: Yes, used sample code that was
        ChatFrame_AddMessageEventFilter("CHAT_MSG_WHISPER_INFORM", function() print(1) return true end)

Yes, called it before and after, it does increase by one. How am I supposed to find it. I just see that a new function has been added. I don't think it is called. Not getting any ones in the chat with the code above. Yes, tried to always return true with the code above.

Comment: You find it by using a non-anonymous function then seeing if it's in the list returned by `ChatFrame_GetMessageEventFilters`. A function is just a value in Lua. Save the value before passing it to AMEF, then look for it in the list returned by GMEF. If you can't find it, yet the list does increase by one, then someone else is wrapping your function and potentially disabling it. Fortunately, you have the source code to all the addons on your system, so you can find out exactly who is doing this. When you use that sample filter, do you still see your outgoing whispers in the log?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86834/discussion-between-mud-and-thomja).

Comment: I solved it by removing TRP3s filters... I will add code to re-add them when I'm done. But I won't post that as part of my answer.

Comment: It's a very bad practice to have your addon's implementation dependent on the implementation details of another addon. It makes very little sense that another addons filter would prevent your filter from being called. If it was me, I'd want to find out exactly what's going on. \*shrug\*

Comment: Well the addon in question was TotalRP3. I messaged the developer, he didn't really seem to care. This works for me so I'm happy. But I agree.

Answer (score 0):

So I managed to solve my problem by removing to current filters that have been put in place by another addon and then just add my own filter. As Mud pointed out. GMEF was supposed to return functions. I now see how this makes sense. But now I have made the code to remove the functions. If you want to re-add them later on, just store them in a variable until you are done but I won't include this in my answer. I also feel like my answer is kinda half off-topic ish. But to answer my own question. It is supposed to return functions and you can't see the contents of these functions. This is the code I used to remove the functions that were put in there by another addon.

```
function rekkFilters()
local myFilters = ChatFrame_GetMessageEventFilters("CHAT_MSG_WHISPER_INFORM")
  for i in pairs(myFilters) do
    ChatFrame_RemoveMessageEventFilter("CHAT_MSG_WHISPER_INFORM", myFilters[i])
  end
end
local myFilters = ChatFrame_GetMessageEventFilters("CHAT_MSG_WHISPER_INFORM")
rekkFilters()
local myFilters = ChatFrame_GetMessageEventFilters("CHAT_MSG_WHISPER_INFORM")
if myFilters[1] ~= nil then
  rekkFilters()
end
```